# Using POST to update values through HTML form retrieves old values

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I'm working on a CRUD system and currently, I am in the Update section. I have old values from users that need to be updated to new ones through an HTML form.

Right now I am trying to retrieve the POST values from the HTML form set to the post method. After that, I update the user info with the new values gained from the POST request.

```
<?php
$oldId = $_GET['id'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
or die('Verbinding met database server is mislukt.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'crudopdracht')
or die('De database is niet beschikbaar');
$query = "SELECT * FROM gebruikers WHERE id = $oldId";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
or die (mysqli_error($conn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $naam = $row['naam'];
    $leeftijd = $row['leeftijd'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];
    $locatie = $row['locatie'];
};
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="id">ID:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" <?php echo 'placeholder="' . $oldId . '"><br>';?>
    <label for="naam">Naam:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" <?php echo 'placeholder="' . $naam . '"><br>';?>
    <label for="leeftijd">Leeftijd:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="leeftijd" name = "leeftijd" <?php echo 'placeholder="' . $leeftijd . '"><br>';?>
    <label for="gender">Geslacht:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender" <?php echo '[placeholder="' . $gender . '"><br>';?>
    <label for="locatie">Locatie:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="locatie" name = "locatie" <?php echo 'placeholder="' . $locatie . '"><br><br>';?>
    <input type="submit" value="Verstuur" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo 'hello';
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $naam = $_POST["naam"];
    $leeftijd = $_POST["leeftijd"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    $locatie = $_POST["locatie"];
    $query2 = "UPDATE gebruikers SET id = $id, naam = $naam, leeftijd = $leeftijd, gender = $gender, locatie = $locatie WHERE id = $oldId";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
}
?>
```

In my opinion, I expect the values to change to the new ones set in the HTML form, but they always return the old values.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Also, if you do an `echo $query2;` are you getting what you expect to see. If you run this command directly in your database do you get an error? Have you tried looking at your logs to see if any error is occuring?

Comment: @Jens I don't worry extremely much about sql injection at the moment, as I'm studying web development in college and right now our job is to do this. We'll work on preventing sql injection after this, using the current CRUD.

Comment: placeholders aren't submitted to $_POST, you need to use the value attribute

Comment: There are lots of errors in this code (some probably just typos), it needs careful review. Break it down and try to update just one value first of all. Also look into PDO and Prepared Statements to avoid SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @kojow7 , When I put the command into the database, I got an error saying #1054 - Unknown Column new-name-here in 'field list'

Comment: @mattfryercom That didn't fix it, but thank you for telling me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL injection issues aside (as you've stated it isn't in scope of the particular issue), you need to correctly format your SQL query for any non-integer values, so that they are encapsulated with quotes (`'[value]'`).

Your query would current run as:

```
UPDATE gebruikers ( id = somevalue, naam = somevalue, leeftijd = somevalue, gender = somevalue, locatie = somevalue WHERE id = 12345`
```

In this query, SQL would attempt to interpret your values as entities (columns, tables), which is obviously not what you want.

So, **although you should never inject user input values into a query**, the following should fix your issue:

Change

```
$query2 = "UPDATE gebruikers SET id = $id, naam = $naam, leeftijd = $leeftijd, gender = $gender, locatie = $locatie WHERE id = $oldId";
```

to

```
$query2 = "UPDATE gebruikers SET id = $id, naam = '$naam', leeftijd = '$leeftijd', gender = '$gender', locatie = '$locatie' WHERE id = $oldId";`
```

Assuming `id` is an `INT` field, and the others are strings.

Comment: Thank you very much! I apologize for the messy code and I understand the danger of SQL injection and stuff like XSS attacks. This is just for a school assignment and we haven't learned about prepared statements yet.

Comment: @Redshade No problem - it's not always relevant to the question, but often the issues isn't your use of it (as the asker), but someone else's interpretation of the advice (as the audience).  If not disclosed as a warning, someone might read the answer and apply it in a way that they shouldn't.  As long as you understand the risks and are happy that you don't need to handle them :)